# How automatically compare two sentences and replace any value that occur in one sentence but not in the other?

Tags: java, replace, compare

I am working on java project that compare two sentences and do the following:

First sentence is :  `h = A(?X,?X3,?X32)` 
Second sentence is : `b = B(?X), C(?Y,?X32), W(?X3256)`

I want the program compare the two sentences and if any argument exist in h, but not in b change the ? to ! only for this argument and only in h sentence, so the above h sentence shouls become: 
First sentence become : `h = A(?X,!X3,?X32)`

I tried to use this:

```
if(h.contains("?X3") && !(b.contains("?X3"))) {
    h=h.replaceAll("\\?X3","!X3");
}
```

But this will replace both ?X3 and ?X32. It produce this result:
 `h = A(?X,!X3,!X32)`, which is wrong  because X32 is exist in b.

Also, I want to do a general method the replace any argument that occur in h but not in b,  because the argument could be any value (letters or numbers).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Please try to elaborate your input data and expected results, and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because your requirements appear to contradict to your example.  `?X3` exists in both strings and no replacement takes place in either input string.  Also, it is not clear whether you want to replace _all_ `?` to `!`.  Also, you try to replace some value in `s1` after you checked that it is not contained in `s1` - so this cannot work.

Comment: sorry for the confusing in my questions, I edited it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need to detect some alphanumeric 'arguments' in your sentences starting with `"?"`, you may need to implement some helper method to split a sentence into these specific arguments and then check if some argument is not contained in the second sentence.

For example:

```
// helper split
private static List<String> split(String s) {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    int start = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == '?') {
            result.add(s.substring(start, i));
            start = i++;
            while (i < s.length()) {
                c = s.charAt(i);
                if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(c)) {
                    result.add(s.substring(start, i));
                    start = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }       
    }
    result.add(s.substring(start, s.length()));

    // result.forEach(System.out::println);  // debug print
    return result;
}
```

Then it can be tested as follows:

```
String h = "A(?X,?X3,?X32)";
String b = "B(?X), C(?Y,?X32), W(?X3256)";

List<String> argsH = split(h);
List<String> argsB = split(b);

for (int i = 0; i < argsH.size(); i++) {
    String arg = argsH.get(i);
    if (arg.startsWith("?") && !argsB.contains(arg)) {
        argsH.set(i, "!" + arg.substring(1));
    }
}
h = String.join("", argsH);
System.out.println("Updated: " + h);

// output
Updated: A(?X,!X3,?X32)
```